# how to put dialog box position in the center of the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, dialog

I want to open my dialog box at the center of the page, here is my code:

```
 $(function() {
   $('#app').button().click(function(){   //bind handlers
   $("#somediv").load('<?php echo CController::createUrl('jobs/apply', array('idJob'=>1)); ?>').dialog({modal:true}); 
   $("#somediv").dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
});
 });
```

Comment: should open in center by default...where is yours opening? Create a demmo that replicates it

Answer (score 0):

Add the CSS rule: `margin: 0 auto;` to your dialog box.
If you want it to pop over your web page, then place your dialog box inside a div that has the following attributes:

```
div.your-class {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then add `margin: 0 auto;`to your dialog box `div`

Answer (score 0):

From jquery docs - http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position - that option you're trying to use is already in "center/center" position.

> Default: { my: "center", at: "center", of: window }

You should look for a problem in your css files and/or use the answer provided by Valentin Mercier.